# tmp_name null in 000webhost using Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am using lumen in 000webhost hosting and can't upload a file because tmp_name is empty. If i'm using `$request->hasFile('image')`, it will return false. And `$_FILES['file']['error']` return 6.
What can I do ?

However, file upload at my localhost run without a problem, And I've tried to follow laravel project installation for 000webhost in here https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323.

```
$file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; //returns empty
$request->hasFile('image') // returns false
```

I expect `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` return a string containing temp_name folder.

upload_max_filesize and post_max_size is 8M so filesize is not an issue.

Thankyou!

Comment: What is the file size? If free server then it might have lower upload limit. Check it

Comment: @mukund the file size is only 8KB and 100KB